# UITableView Delete Control and Delete Button not synced

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uitableview

I have seen a very strange behavior of my table view:
I have enabled the UITableViewEditingStyleDelete, which shows in the editing mode at the left side of the tableView a red "-" control. If I tap on that control, the delete button at the right side appears and the "-" control get turned. Everything okay, but if I do that several times, sometimes the "-" control is horizontal, but the delete button is visible:
[image]

Has that may be something to do with refreshing the tableView? Should I disable them in editing mode?

Had somebody seen something similar to that or has an idea how to resolve it?

Update 05/20/13:
I check now in each NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate callback, if my tableView is in editing and if yes, I don't update the tableView, which would fix that bug. When the tableView returns from the editing in the normal mode, I call [tableView reloadData] so that the tableView is up to date and contains the newest information.

But this destroys the animation. Has somebody an idea, how I can update my tableView without losing the animation? The problem is, that the tableView doesn't know what did happen while it was in the edit mode.

Thank you very much for your help!

Linard

Answer (score 0):

The loss of the animation is just one part of deactivating updates in the edit mode. The other thing is, that if you add or delete one row in the edit mode, you have to implement [tableView reloadData] to.
I think the better solution is, to just deactivate any cell content updates through the NSFetchedResultController. The content changes in my table very often, but that's not that important while editing the cell. And if the table is able to add or delete any cells, which is not deactivated, the tableView rows and sections remain updated, so that you just need to update the rows at the end of the editing mode instead of the entire tableView with [tableView reloadData].
With this solution you have all animations, no additional update code for the tableView while inserting or deleting a row and at the end of the edit mode you have no trouble to update the tableView to the state of your CorePlot data.

Update:
After playing around, I saw, that the bug appears the same way then before, just not that often.
I think the problem is, that [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdates] get called the same way then before and this may cause the bug.
I have no changed back to [tableView reloadData] and I have no deactivated any updates during editing, because that's the only way I've found until now which works (even if I lose my animations).

If someone has an additional idea or some improvements, please let me know.

Linard